# Use Robolectric to test BluetoothAdapter in android 4.3

Tags: android, robolectric

In my android app, there the following code:

```
BluetoothManager bm = (BluetoothManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter ba = bm.getAdapter();
```

I want to do Unit Tests using Robolectric. I am using Robolectric 2.2.
But I found that bm is null, and I don't know how to mock it.

Comment: Maybe abstract away your untestable code with an interface of your own?

Comment: Thank you Machinarius, I found that getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) is a feature over android 4.3, maybe Robolectric 2.2 does not support android 4.3? I'm not sure.

Comment: I am speaking merely from a testing perspective, make it so the unit under test depends on something that abstract bluetooth away into complex operations, that way you can easily mock out the interface and create a real implementation for the production case. I have not used bluetooth or Robolectric before so i can't talk from those standpoints

Answer (score 1):

### The challenge

The challenge with testing for bluetooth and other system services is that **these classes are all final**.

### The hard way (skip and go to powermock solution if you like)

So if you want to inject anything else you need to make a wrapper around the final class and then provide an implementation forwarding to actual bluetooth classes and an alternative one that mocks your stuff. But then all coded needs to be updated to use that wrapper instead of the final classes directly.

### PowerMock solution

[PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) however should be able to handle these [final classes](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockFinal). The summary (follow link for more detail)

- Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassWithFinal.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use PowerMock.createMock(ClassWithFinal.class) to create a mock object for all methods of this class (let's call it mockObject).
- Use PowerMock.replay(mockObject) to change the mock object to replay mode.
- Use PowerMock.verify(mockObject) to change the mock object to verify mode.